# Binding error when using two same User Controls on one parent Window

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I have a User Control defined like this:

XAML:

```
<UserControl>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TabControl x:Name="TabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" >
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Features}" Name="FeaturesListView">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn x:Name="FeatureHeader" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"  />
                                <GridViewColumn x:Name="CounterHeader" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Counter}" />
                                <GridViewColumn x:Name="ExpireDateHeader"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ExpireDate}" />
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```
public partial class LicenseInfoControl : UserControl
{
    public LicenseInfoControl(ShowableLicense license)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = license;
    }
}
```

So, if I use one User Control for one Window:

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <local:LicenseInfoControl x:Name="LicenseInfoControl"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

it works great. But if I use two of them:

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <local:LicenseInfoControl x:Name="FileLicenseInfoControl"/>
        <local:LicenseInfoControl x:Name="SamLicenseInfoControl"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Both ListViews are empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the Binding Error you're getting that you mentioned in your question title?

Comment: @Rachel Both of ListViews are empty if I use 2 User Controls. Other bindings works well in both cases.

Comment: What happens if you set the DataContext of each LicenseInfoControl from code-behind?

Comment: I do it this way already (I just do not have enough space in question ;))
            `InitializeComponent();
            FileLicenseInfoControl.Initilize(fileLic);
            SamLicenseInfoControl.Initilize(samLic);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding worked well. The problem was that if TabControl has one TabItem - it get selected when window loaded and data exposes into it. But if TabControl has two TabItems - no one of the get selected and there's a feeling that binding hasn't worked. But if you select one of Tab Items - data exposes immediately. 
So the decision is set SelectedIndexes at a constructor of window with two User controls (LicenseInfoControl in my case):

```
FileLicenseInfoControl.ProductTabControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
SamLicenseInfoControl.ProductTabControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
```